# Docker container with rabbitmq hostname ( with EC2 Server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, rabbitmqctl

Im trying to create a RabbitMQ Cluster with nodes in separate machines using Dockers in every individual machine and Im having some issues connecting the nodes.
When I get the rabbitMQ host name, it only refers to the container and because of that when I try to join the node to the cluster it fails because it can not find the domain. How could I tell to the RabbitMQ host name the IP of the actual server?

Im trying to connect the nodes in one server with the nodes of another external server, both are EC2 instance, but what information should have the RabbitMQ host name regarding the EC2 instance host to be able to connect from outside?

If I use ip-172-31-12-135.us-west-1.compute.internal, it fails...

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but you can run a docker container with a specific hostname:
docker run  --hostname=Container host name ...

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a cluster all rabbitmq nodes that are to form up a cluster must be accessible by node name (hostname). 
You need to specify a hostname for each docker container with `--hostname` option and to add /etc/host entries for all the other containers, this you can do with `--add-host` option or by manually edditing /etc/hosts file.
So, here is the example for a 3 rabbitmq nodes cluster with docker containers (rabbitmq:3-management image):

First create a network so that you can assign IPs: `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet1`. We are going to have the following:

- 3 docker containers named rab1con, rab2con and rab3con
- IPs respectively will be 172.18.0.11 , -12 and -13
- each of them will have the host name respectively rab1, rab2 and rab3
- all of the must share the same erlang cookie

Spin up the first one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.11 --hostname rab1 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --add-host rab3:172.18.0.13 --name rab1con -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

second one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.12 --hostname rab2 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --add-host rab3:172.18.0.13 --name rab2con -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

last one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.13 --hostname rab3 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --name rab3con -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here' rabbitmq:3-management
```

Than in contaner rab2con do

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rab1
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

and the same in rab3con and that's it.

EDIT: Since the question is about milti-host docker network, an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#an-overlay-network) should be used.

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding connections between external servers?

Comment: They are in the same subnet and can access each other based on the hostname. What else do you need?

Comment: But Im referring to dockers with RabbitMQ in different servers..not multiple dockers in the same servers

Comment: Sorry missed that. Then use overlay network https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#an-overlay-network

Comment: Thank you, I added it to your answer as with that you have the full solution. However Im going to test it before giving the full validation

Comment: Please provide your comment regarding the network as information in the response as without that it doesnt answer my question..

Comment: You are welcome. Hopefully I have understood what you said and edited the answer in the intended way.